# Can Marketing Cloud be used for B2B?

Tags: marketing-cloud, pardot

I always heard that for B2B Pardot is more suitable than Marketing Cloud, which is preferred for a B2C model. Is there any reason other than the license price?
I am not asking for an opinion but objective comparation. What is offering a feature than another one do not offer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I normally say that Pardot is a tool, while Marketing Cloud is a platform. Hence you can pretty quickly be up and running on Pardot, while Marketing Cloud takes substantially more work to create a similar feature set to what you are getting OOTB on Pardot. This applies especially to lead scoring setup, which is near impossible to implement on Marketing Cloud in a way which would make it as easy to maintain as the one found in Pardot.

My own personal observations on why Pardot is superior to MC in the areas of B2B:

1. Two-way integration with Sales Cloud makes it easy to maintain a consistent master data for your leads and contacts across both platforms
2. Easy to implement tracking scripts, for tracking your visitor across your website, allowing for scoring and adding to lists based on behaviour in near real time.
3. Lead scoring configuration is user friendly, and is quick to set up.
4. Advanced logic in forms allows you to build progressive profiling flows using a.o. Dependent Fields
5. Lightning Component with comprehensive insights into engagement history

Overall speaking, Pardot is super marketer-friendly, offers extensive two-way integration with Sales Cloud and provides valuable features for lead nurturing OOTB. If you were to build these on Marketing Cloud, you will spend, depending on your ambitions, easily more than 1000 hours. And you will still be left with features which are not near as advanced and user friendly as in Pardot. There is a number of third party apps which you can use with Marketing Cloud to improve lead scoring, e.g. SalesWings, but my experience with these is not too promising, as they offer what I would call very basic functionality.

On the other hand, you quickly run into limitations with Pardot. You are missing Automation Studio, ability to use advanced personalisation, data processing and integration capabilities of SSJS/AmpScript, extensive API, etc, which IMHO make SFMC a much more comprehensive platform which is much more scalable than Pardot. But for the quickly-up-and-running-B2B-use-cases, Pardot will be superior.

Comment: +1, good summary. Extensibility (via scripting or otherwise) is the major issue with Pardot. Its APIs have gotten much better over last few major releases. Advanced personalization goes back to scripting. It has clunky ways of achieving somewhat advanced scenarios, e.g. snippets. If there was a middle ground between MC and Pardot, it would have been so sweet. Alas..

Comment: thanks @lukasLonow, other than Lead Scoring/Nurturing, all the other feature can be obtained in Marketing Cloud as well, is it correct?

Comment: Well, @eeadev - not entirely, no. You are looking into a lot of customisations and suboptimal solutions, if you plan on building Pardot features on MC. E.g. progressive profiling forms with dependent fields: can you build it on MC? Yes! Will you be able to have a user friendly form designer with completion actions? No!

Comment: Thanks Lukas Lunow